# Determining When Core Data ManagedObject is Update

Tags: multithreading, core-data, listener

I have a web-based API that allows users to download data that has changed since the last time they downloaded data.

I only want to change the UpdatedOn date once Core Data is actually done updating. The parsing of this data occurs on a separate thread.

Since I save changes to my Entities as I cycle repeatedly through the data, so I do not want to change the UpdatedOn date until all changes are saved. Otherwise, any type of interruption in service would give the user incomplete data which could not be recovered without deleting records altogether.

Would this be best accomplished with Broadcast/Listener (not sure I am using right term here) sent/received when the parsing thread finishes executing?

Comment: Have you considered using [`NSNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) & [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If so this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) may assist .

Comment: Good article, @andrewbuilder. Helped me find some good examples!

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate persistent store to write your changes as you work through them. Change your UpdatedOn if the entire update succeeds, and then move the new persistent store into the old persistent store's place.

Alternatively, do your updates in a child context, which you throw away without saving if your update fails.

Comment: Hal, would I still not need a NSNotificationCenter call to verify when either this persistent store or child context was completed? What would be the advantage of this over simply using NSNotification?

Comment: Those are the same thing. You must use NSNotificationCenter to register for the NSNotification calls.